# How do I handle many-to-many relationships in the view so that the relationship is persisted automatically by Entity Framework 4.3?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4.3

Let's say I have three entities declared:

### Product

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    public Store Store { get; set; }

    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

### Store

```
public class Store
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

### Category

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

There's a one-to-many relationship between `Store` and `Product`, and a many-to-many between `Product` and `Category`.

I'm trying to create a new `Product`. In the controller, I declare:

```
public ViewResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.StoreId = new SelectList(db.Stores, "Id", "Name");
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Create(Product product)
{
    db.Products.Add(product);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Then in the view, I just simply add this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("StoreId")
```

And the dropdown of all stores shows properly to the user. On the POST create, Entity Framework is smart enough to ignore `Product.StoreId` when saving the product and instead uses it to associate the product with an existing store in the DB. This all works really great and is almost magical in how easy it is.

My question is, is it possible to apply the same out-of-the-box behavior for many-to-many relationships as well? I tried creating a new `Product.CategoryIds` List, and then used the same pattern:

### Controller

```
ViewBag.CategoryIds = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "Name");
```

### View

```
@Html.ListBox("CategoryIds")
```

This will display the categories in a multi-select listbox properly. However, when I save the product this time, the categories do not get automatically associated with the product, and the products end up not having any categories.

Does anyone know how to get this working properly?

Comment: The reason it works for Store is because your Product class has a StoreId property. It does not have a "CategoryIds" property. This is where you see the magic happening.

Comment: Yes, but I said in my question that I added a `CategoryIds` property and it did not work.